# Read column wise values using XLSX

Tags: node.js, xlsx

How to read Column wise values from excel using nodejs(node-xlsx) ? Please advise.

I want to read Col A data, then Col B and so on, if any data exists in other columns, then put data in array.

I am able to read A1, B1, A2, B2... this way but not A1, A2, A3... then B1, B2, B3... etc.

[Sample column wise data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sfztn.png)

I did custom way but not able to go to col C dynamically.

```js
const xlsxfile = require("xlsx");
var arr = [];

const spreadsheet = xlsxfile.readFile('./Code.xlsx');

const sheets = spreadsheet.SheetNames;
console.log('Sheet Names -- ' + sheets);

const firstSheetName = sheets[0];
const firstSheet = spreadsheet.Sheets[firstSheetName];

console.log(firstSheet);

for (z in firstSheet) {
    if (z[0] === '!') continue;
    //parse out the column, row, and value
    var tt = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
        if (!isNaN(z[i])) {
            tt = i;
            break;
        }
    };
    var col = z.substring(0, tt);
    var row = parseInt(z.substring(tt));
    
    for (; ; row++) { // looping over all rows in a column
        
        const firstCol = firstSheet[col+''+row];
        
        if (!firstCol) {
            break;
        }
        let value = firstCol.w;
        //console.log(value);

        if (value)
            if (!arr.includes(value))
                arr.push(value);
            else
                continue;    
        else    
            break;  
    }                                                                    
}

console.log('final array = '+arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

I somehow achieved my goal in very bad way. In top most loop it's always trying to get A1, B1, C1 like that. But in between I hijacked and looping all rows.

So in that way, I am keeping one track of what's my last column and comparing in next is same column or new column. if same column, I am existing.

But is there any better way to get all values may be in array format column wise?

```js
const xlsxfile = require("xlsx");
var arr = [];

const spreadsheet = xlsxfile.readFile('./Code.xlsx');

const sheets = spreadsheet.SheetNames;
console.log('Sheet Names -- ' + sheets);

const firstSheetName = sheets[0];
const firstSheet = spreadsheet.Sheets[firstSheetName];

console.log(firstSheet);

let earliercol = []; // keeping a track

for (z in firstSheet) {
    if (z[0] === '!') continue;
    //parse out the column, row, and value
    let tt = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < z.length; i++) {
        if (!isNaN(z[i])) {
            tt = i;
            break;
        }
    };
    let col = z.substring(0, tt);
    let row = parseInt(z.substring(tt));
    
    if (earliercol.includes(col)) // checking current col already traversed or not
    break;

earliercol.push(col); // assigning current col name

    //var value = worksheet[z].v;
    for (; ; row++) {
        //const firstCol = firstSheet['A' + i];
        const firstCol = firstSheet[col+''+row];
        
        if (!firstCol) {
            break;
        }
        let value = firstCol.w;
        //console.log(value);

        if (value)
            if (!arr.includes(value))
                arr.push(value);
            else
                continue;    
        else    
            break;  
    }                                                                    
}

console.log('final array = '+arr);
```